# I have a text file of a grid that has x y z coordinates and varying lengths of the sides of the cells(sx, sy and sz)

Tags: python-3.x, vtk, maya-api

I have a text file of a grid that has x y z coordinates (of cell centers and are in UTM) and varying lengths of the sides of the cells(sx, sy and sz). The points are random points. I would like to plot this in Python. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

```
 x       y          z     sx    sy   sz
 584597 1848923    210   143    53   143      
 584885 1848927    210   143    62   143      
 585173 1853185    210   143   224   143
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and add the error message you are getting:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As far as how? I would start by:

1) using readline, you split each by the " "(space) values

2) create dict with a for loop, and setting the key.. x y z etc...

3) ??  You say you want to plot but since I don't know the end game here; I imagine matploit should be the goto forgraphical plotting

4) As to the other variables, the non-coordinantes, it's up to you in how you want to correlate/express these values.

Comment: Matplotlib is ok for 2d plots, but since the data is 3d, RB123 might be looking for something different. I can think of 2 things: 1) plot projections on a/some planes in matplotlib, and 2) create a vtkPolyData with, maybe, spheres at the point locations, that can be viewed interactively in e.g. paraview.